# Jquery ui selecetable - get HTML of selected items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

i have code example that works fine to get index of selected items.

```
 <script>
     $(function() {
        $( "table" ).selectable({
           selected: function() {
              filter: ".td_to_allow_select",
              var result = $( "#result" ).empty();
              $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                 var index = $( "#table .td_to_allow_select" ).index( this );
                 result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
              });
           }
        });
     });
  </script>
```

my problem is when i try to get the html of div selected, each way i try i get only the html of first ".td_to_allow_select".
the table looks like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>text</td><td class="td_to_allow_select">3454</td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>text</td><td class="td_to_allow_select">4534</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td>text</td><td class="td_to_allow_select">7688</td>
 </tr>>
</table>
```

everything i tried i got only the first TD HTML 3 times "3454 3454 3454".
how could i get the HTML of the TD selected? 
or does anyone has another way to get html of TD when mouse selects it?
thanks.

Comment: Not sure you post is right around `selected: function() { filter: ".td_to_allow_select", var result`

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure what do you mean, but here is the JS I wrote for you:

```
$("td:first-child").on("tdClick", function(){
    alert($(this).text());

})

$("tr").on("click", function(){
    //var txt = $(this).html();
    //alert(txt);
    $("td:first-child").trigger("tdClick");
});
```

Please refer to : 
http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/s7j8xL74/